Wrong sign in co-state of optimal control problem
Consider the following deterministic optimisation problem
\begin{align}
J(t) = \min_{c(t)} \ & \frac{1}{2} \int_0^\infty e^{-\delta u} \left( x(u)^2 + \lambda y(u)^2 \right) du \\
s.t. \ &c(t) \geq 0
\end{align}
where $c(t)$ is the control, and $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ are the state variables with dynamics:
\begin{align}
x'(t) &= c(t) - y(t) - a \\
y'(t) &= \delta y(t) - b x(t)
\end{align}
To solve the problem:

First, I write the Hamiltonian:
\begin{align}
H = - \frac{1}{2} \left( x(u)^2 + \lambda y(u)^2 \right) + J_{x}(t) ( c(t) - y(t) - a ) + J_{y}(t) \left( \delta y(t) - b x(t) \right)
\end{align}
where $J_{x}(t)$ and $J_{y}(t)$ denote the derivatives of the value function with respect to the states (i.e. the co-states). Notice that I added a minus in front of the loss as we are minimising.

Then, I write the extended Hamiltonian:
\begin{align}
L = H + \mu(t) c(t)
\end{align}
where $\mu(t)$ is the Lagrange multiplier.

The complementary slackness conditions are:
\begin{align}
\mu(t) &\geq 0 \\
\mu(t) c(t) &= 0
\end{align}

Since the Hamiltonian is linear in the control, I know it's a bang-bang solution:
\begin{align}
c(t) =
\begin{cases}
+ \infty & \text{if} \ J_{x}(t) > 0 \\
\text{any} & \text{if} \ J_{x}(t) = 0 \\
0 & \text{if} \ J_{x}(t) < 0
\end{cases}
\end{align}

I also know that the optimal control must satisfy:
\begin{align}
L_{c} &= 0 \rightarrow J_{x}(t) = - \mu(t) \nonumber
\end{align}
which from the slackness conditions implies $J_x(t) \leq 0$, i.e. the optimal control either is $c(t) = 0$ or takes a singular solution.


Question
I am reading this paper that says that $J_x(t) \geq 0$ and the optimal control either is $c(t) = 0$ or takes a singular solution. Why is the sign of my $J_x(t)$ the opposite? The only think the paper writes is the Hamiltonian, which differently from mine does not have the minus sign in front.
